# optimize boolean array size in json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, binary

I've written a small leveldesigner for a zelda-like game (rpg)
Wheter or not some place ( 16x16 square can be walked on is precalculated when the map is saved from the level designer)
This map is then loaded into the game.

walkable squares (tiles) are stored in a massive array of arrays (x,y)

Let's say it's a tiny 3x3 map, the json would look like this:

```
walls = [[true,true, true],
         [true,false,true],
         [true,true, true]]
```

meaning only the center block is walkable (1x1 is **not** a wall == false)

now I did use booleans so I could optimize space, I could technically store 8 blocks information in 1 byte.

but the way it is stored now feels ULTRA un optimized as each block is stored as a string representation of a boolean inside the json file.

is there a way to store raw binary data of the array, or create my own protocol and store this unregular binary data in the json?

this array is obviously never interpreted by a human as it is generated, so I don't mind it being unreadable.

Comment: You can use integers, as long as you stick to 50ish bits. A little bit less crazy and somewhat closer to readable (or at least, formattable) would be hex strings.

Comment: There's no binary data type in JSON, but you can translate a binary value to decimal, or more effectively, to a string, i.e. a single character per byte.

Comment: Vincent, have a look at my answer. It can reduce this specific "walls" array to: `7|5|7`, and convert it back again.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, let's use integers instead:

```
walls = [[1,1,1],
         [1,0,1],
         [1,1,1]]
```

A `1` even looks like a wall ;-)

Stringifying this will give you something quite a bit shorter than booleans:

```
JSON.stringify(walls) // "[[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]"
```

You can also stringify the map yourself, into a more compact format:

```js
const walls = [[1,1,1],
             [1,0,1],
             [1,1,1]];

// Stringified
const map = walls.map(r => r.join('')).join('|');
console.log(map); // "111|101|111"

// Unstringified
const wallsAgain = map.split('|').map(r => r.split('').map(Number))
console.log(wallsAgain);

// Or back to your boolean format.
const wallsToBooleans = map.split('|').map(r => r.split('').map(c => c === '1'))
console.log(wallsToBooleans)
```

---

## Now things get interesting...

If we're really going crazy, we can make the stringified map even shorter by converting the "binary" representation of `1/0` to a different base:

```js
const walls = [[1,1,1,1,1],
               [1,0,1,0,1],
               [1,1,1,1,1],
               [1,0,1,0,1],
               [1,1,1,1,1]];

const mapBase = 36;

const map = stringifyMap(walls);

console.log(map);                           // Stringified ("1f|15|1f|15|1f")
console.log(parseMap(map));                 // Unstringified
console.log(parseMap(map, c => c === '1')); // Or back to your boolean format.

// Walls to string
function stringifyMap(walls) {
  return walls.map(r => rowToStr(r)).join('|');
}

// String to walls
function parseMap(map, cellParser) {
  return map.split('|')
    .map(r => strToRow(r)
      .map(cellParser || Number))

}

function rowToStr(row){
  const num = parseInt(row.join(''), 2); // Parse the `'10101'` to int,
  return num.toString(mapBase);          // Then convert it to a higher base;
}

function strToRow(str){
  const num = parseInt(str, mapBase); // Parse the higher base to int,
  return num.toString(2).split('');   // Then convert it to binary.
}
```